# Can ZMQ publish message to specific client by pub-sub socket?

Tags: sockets, zeromq, pyzmq, jzmq

I am using pub/Sub Socket and currently the server subscribe byte[0] (all topics)
while client subscribe byte[16] - a specific header as topic

However, I cannot stop client to subscribe byte[0] which can receive all other messages.

My application is a like a app game which has one single server using ZMQ as connection
and many clients have a ZMQ sockets to talk with server.

What pattern or socket I should use in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Have you successfully implemented a solution to stop clients from subscribing all topics? Can you briefly tell what was your final solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*" ... **cannot stop client** to subscribe byte[0] which can **receive all other messages."***

---

### Stopping a "subscribe to all" mode of the SUB client

For the ZMQ **`PUB`**/**`SUB`** Formal Communication Pattern archetype, the **`SUB`** client has to submit it's subscription request ( via `zmq_setsockopt()` ).

**`PUB`**-side ( a Game Server ) has got no option to do that from it's side.

There is no-subscription state right on a creation of a new `SUB` socket, thus an absolutely restrictive filter, thas no message pass through. ( For furhter details on methods for `SUBSCRIBE` / `UNSUBSCRIBE` ref. below )

---

### ZeroMQ specification details setting for this:

```
int zmq_setsockopt (       void   *socket,
                           int     option_name,
                     const void   *option_value,
                           size_t  option_len
                     );

Caution: only ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE
              ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE
              ZMQ_LINGER
         take effect immediately,
         other options are active only for subsequent socket bind/connects.
```

**`ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE`**: **Establish message filter**

The `ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE` option shall establish a new message filter on a `ZMQ_SUB` socket. Newly created `ZMQ_SUB` sockets shall filter out all incoming messages, therefore you should call this option to establish an initial message filter.

An **empty** `option_value` **of length zero** shall subscribe to all incoming messages.

A **non-empty** `option_value` shall subscribe to all messages **beginning** with the specified prefix.

**Multiple filters may be attached** to a single `ZMQ_SUB` socket, in which case a message shall be accepted if it matches at least one filter.

**`ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE`**: **Remove message filter**

The `ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE` option shall remove an existing message filter on a `ZMQ_SUB` socket. The filter specified **must match** an existing filter previously established with the `ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE` option. If the socket has several instances of the same filter attached the `ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE` option shall **remove only one** instance, leaving the rest in place and functional.

---

### How to enforce an ad-hoc, server-dictated, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE restrictions?

This is possible via extending the messaging layer and adding a control-mode socket, that will carry server-initiated settings for the client `ZMQ_SUB` messages filtering.

Upon receiving a new, the server-dictated, `ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE`/`ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE` setting, the `ZMQ_SUB` client side code will simply handle that request and add `zmq_setsockopt()` accordingly.

FSA-driven grammars for this approach are rich of further possibilites, so will allow any Game Server / Game Community to smoothly go this way.

---

### What pattern or socket I should use?

ZeroMQ is rather a library of LEGO-style elements to get assembled into a bigger picture.

Expecting such a smart library to have a one-size-fits-all ***ninja-element*** is on a closer look an **oxymoron**.

So, to avoid a "*Never-ending-story*" of adding "*although this ... and also that ...*"

1. **Review** all requirements and & **list** features for the end-to-end scaleable solution,
2. **Design** a messaging concept & **validate** it to meet all the listed requirements & cover all features in [1]
3. **Implement** [2]
4. **Test** [3] & **correct** it for meeting 1:1 the end-to-end specification [1]
5. **Enjoy** it. You have done it end-to-end right.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Although the SUB client has to submit it's restrictive subscription request, I cannot enforce it to subscribe by filter. Although my application can do, my concern is if any hacker/attack can easily remove the message filter by themselves and subscribe all messages.

Comment: @Billy Let's address the issue step by step. [a] **Yes**, SUB-client has to submit (any) subscription request. [b] **Yes**, you can enforce  the content of the subscription request, by an application-specific/hardware-id/et al default value first & than reading it from server control-channel as described above. [c] **Yes**, there is always a way to "hack" & those who indeed care may implement adequately higher levels of authetication / transaction-state / transaction-content protection, up to a MIL-STD-level robust solution.

Comment: I change to Dealer-Router-Dealer model. So that clients work as dealer and server has a router socket and dealer to handle the request. However, the latency for server to receive client's message become 100x more. I wonder if it is because there is something built for each dealer message. And if pub-sub is by-nature much faster than router-dealer socket. Thank you.

Comment: @Billy **What** is your **Design** [2] **target** for **n** -`clients` and **what**  is your **Design** [2] **target** for maximum **acceptable** `latency[ms]` so as to speak in hard facts?

Comment: previous pub-sub is within 10 ms (without network latency), right now is 1 sec. Our acceptable latency is within 10 ms anyway. There must be something wrong for the dealer-router-dealer pattern... target client is over thousand per second.

Comment: Very updated.. I change the number of worker dealer to more than 1 (previous was 1), the speed is much faster... within 50ms now. I don't know why because I am testing by one client only currently...

Comment: @Billy As far as my past experience goes, there are **several order of magnitudes less frequent a case** when there is *"something wrong"* with the ZeroMQ pattern **compared to** the cases of inappropriate archetype use or mis-understood logic of the Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern archetype use in some more complex distributed messaging system or a Design flaw.