# ZMQ subscriber filtering

Tags: sockets, zeromq

According to the following discussion

[Can ZMQ publish message to specific client by pub-sub socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696501/can-zmq-publish-message-to-specific-client-by-pub-sub-socket)

there seems to be no possibility of preventing a subscriber from receiving all messages when he does not provide a filter.

**Is it possible** that a subscriber that provides no filter will not receive any messages? I.e., **a subscriber does only receive messages, if he knows an exact filter** (no wildcards, etc).

Comment: No way... Don't you have a mystery byte, for example 0x02 or the like?

Comment: How might a mystery byte will help here?

Comment: You go subscribing that mystery byte just by your one subscriber...? Or you design your code to PUSH/PULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bit confusion on subject. Let's de-mystify the **`PUB-SUB`**

---

### Case 1) a <kbd>SUB</kbd> who "does not provide a filter"

This is btw a default initial state right after an instantiation

```
aSub_signallingChannelEND = aCentralCONTEXT.socket( zmq.SUB )
```

In this initial state, there is no valid subscription (pre-)set, naturally, as the `Context()` is a rational process ( not a Norn ) and as such it cannot a-priori assume any such universally valid subscription-key ( and it would be pretty Orwellish if it could, wouldn't it? ) so as to indoctrinate a `SUB`-instance to have it "breathed-in" since it's birth.

In original **ZeroMQ v2.x** ( note, that this was documented not to be valid for the newest version o the ZeroMQ library ) this state however does not mean the **`SUB`** side does not get physically receive any messages. The v2.x subscription filtering was performed ( be it due to performance motivated decisions or not ) on **`SUB`**-side, so the wire-level ***detection of "un-authorised" messages was still possible***

---

### Case 2) a <kbd>SUB</kbd> who "did provide a super-set of all filters"

**Short version:**
In principle, **`PUB`**-side per-se has no controls to discriminate any **`SUB`**-side decision about what to subscribe-to and what to unsubscribe-from.

---

### How to get it work in a given manner?

As **`PUB-SUB`** messaging pattern is defined this way, you have to help yourself with either a smart-layered setup for authentication needs you have beyond the `PUB-SUB` pattern, or one can use other means for added authentication based protection ( for example a tailor-made right/key for authentication-based selective-ability for code/decode content-use to highlight some of the possible approaches ).